# How to prevent auto scrolling of EditText when keyboard appears on Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

Even i put scrollview or not, when my edit text request focus and keyboard appears, my view automatically scrolled to top a little bit. It breaks my design. I have to prevent this.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addthis

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

   android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

in the manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your Manifext.xml under your **activity tag** and make sure your **activity must not use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"**.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Please try it and let me know your comments if still you have problem..!!